# Retrieve my comment history from my YouTube channel

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to retrieve list of my own comments from my channel via YouTube API but can not find a way to do it. This is available via the history (https://www.youtube.com/feed/history/comment_history), but there is no mention in API documentation (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs).

Going through liked/disliked videos, then retrieving all video comments and searching for myself seems way too complicated, slow and will use too much quota.

Is there a better way to get own comments via the API?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the only way to get this information is to scrape it from  https://www.youtube.com/feed/history/comment_history

With that page loaded, run the following code in the developer console in order to load your entire comment history into the DOM. This script just repeatedly scrolls to the bottom of the page until there are no more comments to load.

```js
let previousScrollHeight = 0;
let retries = 3;
let currentRetry = 0;
let initialInterval = 1000; // Initial interval duration in milliseconds

function scrollToBottomIfScrollHeightIncreases() {
  const currentScrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;

  if (currentScrollHeight > previousScrollHeight) {
    // Scroll to the end of the webpage
    window.scrollTo(0, currentScrollHeight);
    previousScrollHeight = currentScrollHeight;
    currentRetry = 0; // Reset retry count on successful scroll
  } else if (currentRetry < retries) {
    // Retry with exponential backoff
    currentRetry++;
    const backoffDuration = initialInterval * 2 ** currentRetry;
    console.log('Retrying with interval of ', backoffDuration, ' ms.');
    clearInterval(scrollInterval);
    scrollInterval = setInterval(
      scrollToBottomIfScrollHeightIncreases,
      backoffDuration
    );
  } else {
    // Stop the interval if scrollHeight stops increasing and retries are exhausted
    clearInterval(scrollInterval);
    console.log('Done');
  }
}

// Call the function every second initially
let scrollInterval = setInterval(scrollToBottomIfScrollHeightIncreases, initialInterval);
```

Then, running the following code will extract the each comment and related video URL into an array. Note that this code will break in the future if/when Google changes the structure of the HTML enough that the query selectors aren't accurate anymore.

```js
const cardElements =
  document
    .querySelectorAll('div[aria-label="Card showing an activity from YouTube"]');

const extractedData =
  Array
    .from(cardElements)
    .map(extractCardInfo);

console.log(extractedData);

function extractCardInfo(cardElement) {
  const userComment =
    cardElement
      .querySelector('div[tabindex="-1"]')
      .textContent.trim();

  const videoUrl =
    cardElement
      .querySelector('a[aria-label="Play video"]')
      .getAttribute('href');

  return {
    userComment,
    videoUrl,
  };
}
```

I wasn't able to figure out how to get the date and timestamp for each comment. (Getting the timestamp by itself is easy but useless without the corresponding date.) Maybe someone else here can help?